# How do I retrieve the link of an image through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to make my program fetch the link of an image and then store it as a string in a variable.
This is the xpath of the image. I need to do it through xpaths because the xpaths on the website are very similar bar the "/article[x]". This allow me to increase the number with a variable so that I can go through all the xpaths on the page.

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/article[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a/img
```

Picture of the website that I'm trying to retrieve the links of the image
[image: Picture of the website that I'm trying to retrieve the links of the image]

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import tkinter
import time

Anime = input("Enter Anime:")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\amete\Documents\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://myanimelist.net/search/all?q=one%20piece&cat=all")

search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="q"]')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="q"]')))
#  Clears the field
search.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
search.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)

#  The field is now cleared and the program can type whatever it wants
search.send_keys(Anime)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#  Accept the cookies
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="qc-cmp2-ui"]/div[2]/div/button[3]'))).click()

#  Added this wait
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//h2[@id="anime"]//ancestor::div[@class="content-left"]//article[1]/div[contains(@class, "list")][1]/div[contains(@class, "information")]/a[1]')))
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h2[@id="anime"]//ancestor::div[@class="content-left"]//article[1]/div[contains(@class, "list")][1]/div[contains(@class, "information")]/a[1]').text

piclink = driver.('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/article[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a/img')
print (piclink)
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried including opening the web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get it like this (specify the attribute)

```
piclink = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/article[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a/img').get_attribute('src')
print(piclink)
```

Comment: When I added it to my code it returned "None"

Comment: I got it to work.
Instead of "href", I used "src"

Comment: yea i thought is a link :D